# Can not run build file in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created small application and I got build file see the image my build file structure [image], if I move to server my build file is not working.
I used my command **npm run build** what I am missing, check my **next.config.js** Localhost server working fine. could you please solve this issue.

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: 'build',
  images: {
    domains: ["dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net"],
  },
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2"
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: What error you are reciving when you are deploying, and how app is deployed ?

Comment: I moved build file directly my server root public_html/htdocs/ folder after check my server page is empty.

Comment: What's the error when running on prod ?

Comment: No error attached above my error. Is correct my build file structure

Comment: @karthik, Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/63518597/7785337

Comment: If you are deploying in sub path not root, you need to config your app